# Laravel и React или Vue

Tags: reactjs, laravel, vue.js

Прошу прощения может быть за глупый вопрос. Но есть ли смысл использовать React или Vue вместе с бэком на таком PHP фреймворке, как Laravel. Или это слишком костыльно получается?

Comment: Собственное мнение если используйте Laravel API то react, если внутри laravel -а то vue js :)

Comment: Laravel - это фреймворк для API в Вашем случае. Поэтому хоть с чем используйте, хоть Svelte или Angular. На Laravel только бэкенд и вывод данных теперь (можете вообще Lumen заюать, тот же Laravel, только из разряда "собери сам" меньше зависимостей потянете, будет меньше лагов).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, то есть в этом есть смысл, но придётся отказаться от некоторых функций, например от того же шаблонизатора и работать с бэком преимущественно через API?

Comment: @Maxim Вам не нужен шаблонизатор Blade, у Вас будет шаблонизация на фронте (у Vue так вообще всё очень удобно, очень похоже на ларавелевский шаблонизатор и даже лучше). Да и особо в ларе не нужно будет, что связано с этой вот монолитностью (максимум усложнится немного работа с аутентификацией, там да, придётся отказаться от стандартных сессий в пользу JWT).